# mysql query for selecting afew last rows

Tags: mysql

i want to create a messaging page and i should add a button for showing the older messages in the order as it is.
i have a sample code for it with jquery but i cant write query part.
this is sample of query part:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY id DESC limit $offset, $comnco
```

how can i change this to show the last 5 messages without "DESC".in the same order as it is.for example, if there are 100 queries show the 95,96,97,98,99,100 in order.
thanks

Comment: Still struggling? See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave with the 100 rows, if I get it right, you could do something like that,

```
select * from 'mytable' where id > (select count(*) - 5 from 'mytable');
```

ORDER BY and DESC is not needed. You can adjust it in the same way to your query.

I attach an image with a relevant example.

[image]

Comment: @behzad by offset, you mean 5 in my example, right? You can pass it as a parameter, there are ways for it, depends on how you implement your solution

Comment: if i add another part of cods first $offset is 0 and $comnco is 5 and cods repeated again and then $offset+$comnco and show other 5 mines that 5 and again and... . now where i put $offset and $comco?

Comment: @behzad I am sorry, I don't get it, probably you should add a more detailed example to fully understand it

Comment: ok thanks but i tested your code and it selects all the lines not 5 last lines

Comment: I don't think so, I tested it before posting it ;)

Comment: believe me this is my code : select * from t_users where id > (select count(*) - 5 from t_users)

Comment: Added an image in my answer. As you can see my table has 548 rows (of course I couldn't upload the whole 'select *' and there is no point for it) and by the query I provided, it returns the last 5 in the desired order. So, I don't understand why that shouldn't work for you. In any case, you know your code better.

Comment: I believe you, no worries. :) I worked directly on the table via the terminal. I see that you probably do it via a UI, so I don't know what is going on behind it. It might not take into account at all the query you enter for some reason and, as a result, returns them all.